# Display a message regarding cart discount in header of all the pages in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, header, messages

[image]I am showing one message regarding cart discount in the header of all the pages, but on some pages, the discount is not showing as if the cart is empty.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please share the Screenshot for the same.

Comment: @Sumit I have updated the question

Comment: can you please share the code of displaying this message

Comment: @ASQ I am just debugging/work around of this type so any suggestions for this?

Comment: You need to add the promotion block in the default.xml file in your theme to display it on all pages.

Comment: But Something in mind caught that on some pages, the discount is not showing as if the cart is empty.

Comment: Can you please share the page type (CMS, Catalog, Checkout etc) where this block is not showing?

Comment: @Sumit catalog and product pages.

Comment: I think the added code may be working on the quote items. If the cart quote is empty the message disappears. You need to change the logic of the code.

Comment: @Sumit What if the cart has products?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97675/discussion-between-sumit-and-gajjala-sandeep).